# Issue with parsing data from input box with loop (Average Grade Calculator)

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out a method that allows me to carry the data from a number input box to a loop and allows me to add it and average it. I've narrowed the problem down to the one line in my program.

I'll provide partial code in the hope that someone can tell me where I'm going wrong.  I either get "NaN, null, undefined, or my html textbox code eg `<input type=.... >`.

Here is the code:

```js
function calcGrades() {
  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].cells;
    var sum = 0;

    for (var x = 3; x < cells.length; x++) {
      var cell = cells[x];
      // sum += parseInt(cell.innerHTML)
      // var test = document.getElementById(cell);
      //sum += document.getElementById(table.rows[i].cells[x].value);
      //sum += (table.rows[i].cells[x].innerHTML)
      //sum += document.getElementById();
      //sum += (table.rows[i].cells[x].children[0].value);
      //sum += document.getElementById(table.rows.cell).value;

    }
    var average = sum / cells.length;
    rows[i].innerHTML += "<td>" + average + "</td>";
    }
  }

  function constraint(val) {
    if (Number(val.value) > 100) {
      val.value = 100
    }
  }
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <th> Name </th>
    <th> ID </th>
    <th> 1 (%)</th>
    <th> 2 (%)</th>
    <th> 3 (%)</th>
    <th> 4 (%)</th>
    <th> 5 (%)</th>
    <th> Final % </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align=center> John Doe </td>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> <input type="number" placeholder="-" size="2" maxlength="3" id="s1g1" oninput="constraint(this)"> </td>
    <td> <input type="number" placeholder="-" size="2" maxlength="3" id="s1g2" oninput="constraint(this)"> </td>
    <td> <input type="number" placeholder="-" size="2" maxlength="3" id="s1g3" oninput="constraint(this)"> </td>
    <td> <input type="number" placeholder="-" size="2" maxlength="3" id="s1g4" oninput="constraint(this)"> </td>
    <td> <input type="number" placeholder="-" size="2" maxlength="3" id="s1g5" oninput="constraint(this)"> </td>
    <!--  <td id="s1gf"> - </td> -->
  </tr>

</table>

<button id="calcGrades" onclick="calcGrades()">Calculate Final Grades</button>
```

I've tried every one of the commented out lines, some give NaN, some undefined, some null etc.

I'd rather not hardcode all student grades as I have to do 10 students, which will mean changing a lot of IDs.

Comment: As a starting point, you are getting an error on any input because your `constraint()` function can't be found since it is wrapped inside your `calcGrades()` function. If you run your `calcGrades()` function, you will get another error because you haven't defined (or passed a value to) your `rows` variable.

Comment: @benvc, I made this error copying in from two different code segments with one inbetween however in the actual code it is correct, thanks for spotting that!

Comment: I didn't see rows defined in the JSFiddle, and after playing with it a bit I was able to make it work. Since this is for an assignment I'll say that my recommendation is to create another method (getRows() or similar) that returns an array of arrays, the latter referencing the individual input boxes. After that the rest of your code will be much simpler because you're dealing with simple loops and math with minimal HTML parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `rows` is something like `document.getElementsByTagName('tr')`:

`sum += parseInt(cell.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value)`

Here we search for `input` inside each cell and getting the inputs value. Since the value is of type `String` we need to cast it to `Number` before adding to `sum`

Also, keep in mind that arrays and array-like objects are zero-indexed in js.
So if you want to take cells from 3rd one, we should start from index 2
    `for (var x = 2; x < cells.length; x++) {`

P.S. in HTML5 there's not need for `constrain` function - there's `max` input attribute for your case

P.P.S Here's more compact solution off the top of my head https://jsfiddle.net/pj2L6h4d/3/

Comment: Could you clarify what to do with rows? I've inserted your 'sum' line into my code however it does nothing when I press calculate. See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lambegraham/0gc5qa39/383/ Also I am avoiding the heading row with `for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++)` right? Or am I mistaken

Comment: @GrahamChristopherLambe - you need to define `rows`. In your case, I think you are probably looking for something like `var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')` or `var rows = document.getElementById('tbl').rows`

Comment: After defining rows, I get the usual NaN error and im right back where I started, see: https://jsfiddle.net/lambegraham/0gc5qa39/391/

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Didn't realize I needed to place the rows line outside the scope of calcGrades(). One more question, It wont run again anymore when I change the grades and press calculate grades. Is there a way to fix this easily?

Comment: Actually, you don't need to. I made it to don't do the same job every time we press the button. It can be placed inside the function as well. The fiddle code didn't work because `rows` was not defined at all.

Comment: @GrahamChristopherLambe Also, you code still has few problems. What if you press the button twice? It will fail because we will have +1 cell. Here's how I'd like to solve it: https://jsfiddle.net/pj2L6h4d/2/

Comment: This is perfect, however I still need to add 9 more rows onto it. Will this last solution work for multiple rows? I'll use your answer as inspiration/help as it is for a college assignment. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: Oops. You're right). This one will work with multiple rows https://jsfiddle.net/pj2L6h4d/3/